# How to style SVG via css?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have this code :

```css
#circleSVG {
 fill : red;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g transform='translate(100,100)'>
    <circle id='#circleSVG' r='5'></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/x2pxx92e/

Is it possible to style the circle via CSS ? And not inline like so (I am using D3) :

```
d3.select('#circleSVG').style('fill','red');
```

Comment: try this `svg circle { fill : red;}`

Comment: @MinalChauhan i need to be able to select it via id/class. That does work though

Comment: It is possible with id and class .. check this .. https://jsfiddle.net/x2pxx92e/4/

Comment: great, @Ashitaka pointed out I hadn't set my ID properly :( Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when adding the `id` to your circle. It should be `id='circleSVG'`, not `id='#circleSVG'`.

With CSS you use `#` to denote an `id` and `.` to denote a class.

Comment: what an idiot I am. Stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: It's ok! We all make those mistakes.

Comment: dont suppose you could take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/x2pxx92e/5/ I add a class on mouseover which should colour the circle orange, yet it doesn't. This is my actual problem I am having in my offline code

Comment: A CSS rule that uses an `id` will always win to a CSS rule that uses a `class`. That's why you shouldn't use `id`s in CSS. Here's your fixed JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x2pxx92e/8/. And here's an even simpler version, using the CSS `:hover` selector: https://jsfiddle.net/x2pxx92e/10/.

Answer (score 0):

remove the # from the ID

```css
/**
* essentially the same CSS just more precise.
**/
svg.foo-class>g>circle {
 fill : red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="foo-class">
    <g transform='translate(100,100)'>
        <circle id='circleSVG' r='5'></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```